# java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom can be resolved

Tags: java, import

I am trying to import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom but the I get the error message "ThreadLocalRandom" can not be resolved. I checked the compiler compliance level under properties -> java compiler and found it to be 1.6. I have read that ThreadLocalRandom was introduced in 1.5 and above, so why does the import fail?

Answer (score 4):

[ThreadLocalRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) has released with Jdk 1.7. Go through the documentation.